# In WPF, how can I have binding on LostFocus but validation on PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to be able to bind a TextBox with the UpdateSourceTrigger set to LostFocus (the default) but to perform validation as the user types in the text. The best I can come up with is to handle the TextChanged event and call a validation method on the view model. I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

My view model listens to property changes in the model in order to update itself (including formatting). I don't want to bind with the UpdateSourceTrigger set to PropertyChanged because that causes the text to be formatted as soon as the user types (for example, the user might want to type "1.2" yet as soon as he/she types "1" the text changes to "1.0" because of the automatic formatting by the view model).

Comment: keep UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged, and add `Delay = 300` (it is milliseconds)

Comment: @ASh Wouldn't that be awkward from a usability perspective? The user might type "1" and if they don't type in ".2" fast enough, they will see the text change to "1.0", which I think would be annoying. Also, the validation won't be immediate but delayed as well (since it happens at binding time).

Comment: IMO, it is a nice side effect that validation is delayed (I personally don't like red borders/exclamations marks when I'm *still typing*). maybe use StringFormat for formatting?

Comment: Can I ask what kind of validation you are applying? In general it seems a bit odd to me to have such a requirement. It's not good to have the view model control the formatting of text. This logic should be implemented in the control. From a data perspective it doesn't matter if the number 1 is treated as 1 or 1.0. It's always 1. In your case it's about presentation. You want to display 1 as 1.0. This is totally independent of the view model pushing a 1 to the model. And obviously it's even independent of validation which proofs that the decimal requirement is not mandatory for data to be valid

Comment: So to force decimal numbers you should override `UIElement.OnLostFocus` or handle the element's routed event `LostFocus` to apply formatting rules after the input is completed. It's fine to have the view model normalize the data for presentation: when reading a 1 from the model, the view model would normalize it to 1.0 before exposing the data to the view. But the view model should not directly adjust user input. You should delegate this sort of cosmetics to the control that collects the input and has awareness of related input events. This would also solve your problem.

Comment: There's no way to split validation and property update conditions out-of-the-box. But you can implement own Control derived from `TextBox` and fix that inside.

Comment: Bind your TextBox to an Intermediate string property that exists only in your ViewModel, instead of binding it directly to your Model. Then set your UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. This will allow validation to be performed only on the Intermediate and not on your Model.  In the code-behind xaml, register to your TextBox's LostFocus event.  Inside of that event handler method, update your Model only if the Intermediate string has no errors, so that Model's text will format.  Finally, in the same method, set your Model's text back into the Intermediate so that the UI updates.

Comment: @BionicCode The validation checks whether the entered text is a number and within a range. To me, view models are a one-to-one representation of the views, so that the presentation is easier to test. As such, my view models contain mostly string properties, even if their corresponding model properties are something else (like int, double, DateTime). This also gives me greater control to what is displayed; for example, we may display a "-" if the underlying model value is double.NaN. I see this kind of presentation logic as the responsibility of the view model because we want it to be testable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on the comment I left, here's an example of how it can be done.

FYI, I used the nuget package MvvmLight for the plumbing.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="{Binding SomeNumberViewModel.IntermediateText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="100" Margin="5"/>
    <Button Content="Hi" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,15" Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainViewModel ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return this.DataContext as MainViewModel;
    }
}
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.myTextBox.LostFocus += MyTextBox_LostFocus;
}

private void MyTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // If the IntermediateText has no validation errors, then update your model.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ViewModel.SomeNumberViewModel[nameof(this.ViewModel.SomeNumberViewModel.IntermediateText)]))
    {
        // Update your model and it gets formatted result
        this.ViewModel.SomeNumberViewModel.ModelValue = this.ViewModel.SomeNumberViewModel.IntermediateText;

        // Then, update your IntermediateText to update the UI.
        this.ViewModel.SomeNumberViewModel.IntermediateText = this.ViewModel.SomeNumberViewModel.ModelValue;
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private SomeNumberViewModel someNumberViewModel;

    public string MyTitle { get => "Stack Overflow Question 65279367"; }

    public SomeNumberViewModel SomeNumberViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.someNumberViewModel == null)
                this.someNumberViewModel = new SomeNumberViewModel(new MyModel());
            return this.someNumberViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

**SomeNumberViewModel.cs**

```
public class SomeNumberViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public SomeNumberViewModel(MyModel model)
    {
        this.Model = model;
    }

    private string intermediateText;
    public string IntermediateText { get => this.intermediateText; set { this.intermediateText = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
    public string ModelValue 
    { 
        get => this.Model.SomeNumber.ToString("0.00"); 
        
        set 
        {
            try
            {
                this.Model.SomeNumber = Convert.ToDouble(value);
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        } 
    }

    public MyModel Model { get; private set; }
    
    public string Error { get => null; }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "IntermediateText":
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.IntermediateText) && FormatErrors(this.IntermediateText))
                        return "Format errors";
                    break;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Only allow numbers to be \d+, or \d+\.\d+
    /// For Example: 1, 1.0, 11.23, etc.
    /// Anything else is a format violation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="numberText"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool FormatErrors(string numberText)
    {
        var valid = (Regex.IsMatch(numberText, @"^(\d+|\d+\.\d+)$"));
        return !valid;
    }
}
```

**MyModel.cs**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public double SomeNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution, except I would try to make the logic more reusable, so that it can be applied to other TextBoxes without duplicating code.

Comment: @redcurry Understood.  It was a first step solution, not a robust solution.